# Как одной командой поменять именами два файла?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Был файл A, скопировал его в B, начал редактировать. Думал, что редактирую B, но на самом деле случайно открыл A. Теперь у меня есть:

- A, с содержимым, которое должно быть в В.
- В, с содержимым, которое
  должно быть в А.

Можно ли как-то просто поменять их местами? Делать `mv` с временным именем неудобно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предустановленной команды, выполняющей это действие, нет. Но ее можно легко добавить: [Как правильно установить новую команду в командную оболочку (shell и другие)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440643/181472)

Готовая команда выглядит так.

```
swap() { mv $1 $1._tmp; mv $2 $1; mv $1._tmp $2; }
```

Теперь ее можно использовать следующим образом:

```
swap a b
```

Ограничения:

- команда не переносит аттрибуты файлов, такие как время создания и права доступа.
- команда не атомарна. Если она прервется,то оставит файлы в неконсистентном состоянии. Например  если `b` нельзя переименовать по какой-либо причине, то `swap` прервется на  `mv $2 $1;` и `a` останется с именем `a.tmp`.

<sub>На основе [ответа Sonique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24457788/2790048)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

У команды `mv` есть опция `-b` — бэкап затираемого файла (по умолчанию добавляет тильду `~` в конце):

```
mv -b first.txt second.txt && mv second.txt~ first.txt
```

Объединил две команды с помощью `&&`: если первый мув не сработает, второй не выполнится (в отличие от `;`).

Comment: Всё правильно, намудрил при редактировании ответа, когда красоту наводил. Поправил. Спасибо!

Comment: Ещё одно уточнение. `&&` это просто объединение команд, чтобы можно было в одну строку писать? Оно на всех шеллах сработает? Я как-то привык к точке с запятой.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, если поставить `;`, то вторая команда выполнится в любом случае. Если через `&&`, то вторая выполнится, только если первая вернула 0 (всё прошло гладко).

Comment: О! Это важная штука (см в моем ответе про атомарность). Не знал про такой синтаксис. Может, вы подробно объясните в ответе про это? Я тогда его приму вместо текущего.

Comment: Ну и тоже в одну команду желательно объединить, все-таки вопрос подразумевает удобство ))

Comment: Про `&&` и `;` дописал. Как в одну команду склеить — не знаю, увы.

Comment: @installero, склеить в одну можно по аналогии с ответом NickVolynkin

Answer (score 2):

Как готовый вариант — [`mmv`](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/mmv)

```
sudo apt-get install mmv # Linux

brew install mmv # OS X
```

Если файлы в одной папке

```
x=file1.test;
y=file2.test;
mmv $x $y$x;
mmv $y $x;
mmv $y$x $y
```

Если в разных,
то разбивайте путь на `${x%/*}/${x##*/}` 
где

```
${x%/*} - каталог
${x##*/} - имя файла
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, стоит познакомиться с `mmv`, пожалуй. А `mmv $x $y$x;` что делает? Это разве не то же самое, что и `mv` с переменными использовать?

Comment: Ну и это все-таки не решение в одну строку.

Comment: или я чего-то не понимаю, или в приведённом примере нет никаких отличий от использования программы `mv` вместо `mmv`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: и мне точно так же кажется.